# Is sound relative when travelling fast?

Tags: special-relativity, acoustics

If I was listening to music through my headphones and travelling close to the speed of light and time is slowing down around me , would the music slow down as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your music player is traveling with you, the music would slow down (as seen by a stationary observer). But you would not notice anything different. That's the beauty of relativity. Your "internal" clock would slow down as much as the music player's clock, and they remain relatively in synch.

Comment: haha we replied almost at the same time, giving the same answer in two different ways :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think that it does not slow down because your headphones travel with you, at the same speed.

Comment: Note that answers starting with "I am not sure" may not always be a good idea... ;)

Comment: @JustSomeone, You could edit the phrase out. . . The answer is fine, otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If by "slowing down" you mean the time it takes for the sound to travel the headphone-ear distance, then I guess not. Meaning the time between production-detection $\Delta t$ of the sound wave is the same in all inertial reference frames, because in a frame relative to the air, sound travels faster than in a frame stationary with respect to air. But in the moving frame it has to travel a longer distance, so these effects cancel out and the time between the two events remains constant.